# Using SimpleTemplateEngine and sending a string is scientific notation

Tags: groovy

Using Groovy-templates: 3.0.10,

The following processing is done

```
def WorkValue = 0.0003
def TestValue = WorkValue .toString() + " GB"
```

Templates:

```
Usage:${TestValue}
```

The output will be Usage:3.0E-4 GB.
Is there anything I can do to make it display as 0.0003 GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code you have, `WorkValue` will have type `BigDecimal` and should output as you are wanting. If `WorkValue` has type `float` or `double`, then it will output according to how you describe but you could get the output you want with:

```
def TestValue = sprintf "%7.4f GB", WorkValue
```